# R strucchange bootstrap test statistic due to nonspherical disturbances

Tags: r, testing, mean, difference, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to find a structural break in the mean of a time-series that is skewed, fat-tailed, and heteroskedastic.  I apply the Andrews(1993) supF-test via the strucchange package.  My understanding is that this is valid even with my nonspherical disturbances.  But I would like to confirm this via bootstrapping.  I would like to estimate the max t-stat from a difference in mean test at each possible breakpoint (just like the Andrews F-stat) and then bootstrap the critical value.  In other words, I want to find my max t-stat in the time-ordered data.  Then scramble the data and find the max t-stat in the scrambled data, 10,000 times.  Then compare the max t-stat from the time-ordered data to a critical value given by the rank 9,500 max t-stat from the unordered data.  Below I generate example data and apply the Andrews supF-test.  Is there any way to "correct" the Andrews test for nonspherical disturbances?  Is there any way to do the bootstrap I am trying to do?

```
library(strucchange)
Thames <- ts(matrix(c(rlnorm(120, 0, 1), rlnorm(120, 2, 2), rlnorm(120, 4, 1)), ncol = 1), frequency = 12, start = c(1985, 1))
fs.thames <- Fstats(Thames ~ 1)
sctest(fs.thames)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) Skewness and heavy tails.** As usual in linear regression models, the asymptotic justification for the inference does not depend on normality and also holds for any other error distribution given zero expectation, homoscedasticity, and lack of correlation (the usual Gauss-Markov assumptions). However, if you have a well-fitting skewed distribution for your data of interest, then you might be able to increase efficiency by basing your inference on the corresponding model. For example, the `glogis` package provides some functions for structural change testing and dating based on a generalized logistic distribution that allows for heavy tails and skewness. Windberger & Zeileis (2014, *Eastern European Economics*, 52, 66–88, [doi:10.2753/EEE0012-8775520304](http://dx.doi.org/10.2753/EEE0012-8775520304)) used this to track changes in skewness of inflation dynamics over time. (See `?breakpoints.glogisfit` for a worked example.) Furthermore, if the skewness itself is not really of interest then a log or sqrt transformation might also be good enough to make the data more "normal".

**(2) Heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation.** As usual in linear regression models, the standard errors (or more broadly the covariance matrix) is not consistent in the presence of heteroscedasticity and/or autocorrelation. One can either try to include this explicitly in the model (e.g., an AR model) or treat it as a nuisance term and employ heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation consistent (HAC) covariance matrices (e.g., Newey-West or Andrews' quadratic spectral kernal HAC). The function `Fstats()` in `strucchange` allows to plug in such estimators, e.g., from the `sandwich` package. See `?durab` for an example using `vcovHC()`.

**(3) Bootstrap and permutation p-values.** The "scrambling" of the time series you describe above sounds more like applying permutations (i.e., sampling without replacement) rather than bootstrap (i.e., sampling with replacement). The former is feasible if the errors are uncorrelated or exchangeable. If you are regressing just on a constant, then you can employ the function `maxstat_test()` from the `coin` package to carry out the supF test. The test statistic is computed in a somewhat different way, however, this can be shown to be equivalent to the supF test in the constant-only case (see Zeileis & Hothorn, 2013, *Statistical Papers*, 54, 931–954, [doi:10.1007/s00362-013-0503-4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00362-013-0503-4)). If you want to perform the permutation test in a more general model, then you would have to do the permutations "by hand" and simply store the test statistic from each permutation. Alternatively, the bootstrap can be applied, e.g., via the `boot` package (where you would still need to write your own small function that computes the test statistic from a given bootstrap sample). There are also some R packages (e.g., `tseries`) that implement bootstrap schemes for dependent series.

Comment: If I want to estimate a breakpoint as the minimum RSS and also correct for heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation do I do this: breakpoints(Thames ~ 1, breaks = 1, vcov. = NeweyWest) (assuming I loaded the right library)?  This does not seem to work.

Comment: For the breakpoint estimation itself no HAC correction is needed because it is just OLS (= minimization of RSS). Only the corresponding confidence intervals need to be adjusted. This is like inference in the linear regression model where you first fit the model by OLS as usual and then only correct the subsequent inference. I've added a second answer that analyzes your simulated Thames data in detail.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding a second answer to analyze the simulated `Thames` data provided. 
Regarding the points from my first general methodological answer: (1) In this case, a `log()` transformation is clearly appropriate to deal with the extreme skewness of the observations. (2) As the data are heteroscedastic, the inference should be based on HC or HAC covariances. Below I employ the Newey-West HAC estimator, although the data are just heteroscedastic but not autocorrelated. The HAC-corrected inference affects the supF test and the confidence intervals for the breakpoint estimates. The breakpoints themselves and the corresponding segment-specific intercepts are estimated by OLS, i.e., treating the heteroscedasticity as a nuisance term. (3) I did not add any bootstrap or permutation inference as the asymptotic inference appears to be convincing enough in this case.

First, we simulate the data using a particular seed. (Note that other seeds may not lead to such clear-cut breakpoint estimates when analyzing the series in levels.)

```
library("strucchange")
set.seed(12)
Thames <- ts(c(rlnorm(120, 0, 1), rlnorm(120, 2, 2), rlnorm(120, 4, 1)),
  frequency = 12, start = c(1985, 1))
```

Then we compute the sequence of HAC-corrected Wald/F statistics and estimate the optimal breakpoints (for m = 1, 2, 3, ... breaks) via OLS. To illustrate how much better this works for the series in logs rather than in levels, both versions are shown.

```
fs_lev <- Fstats(Thames ~ 1, vcov = NeweyWest)
fs_log <- Fstats(log(Thames) ~ 1, vcov = NeweyWest)
bp_lev <- breakpoints(Thames ~ 1) 
bp_log <- breakpoints(log(Thames) ~ 1)
```

The visualization below shows the time series with the fitted intercepts in the first row, the sequence of Wald/F statistics with the 5% critical value of the supF test in the second row, and the residual sum of squares and BIC for the selection of the number of breakpoints in the last row. The code to replicate the graphic is at the end of this answer.

[image: Structural change analysis of simulated Thames data.]

Both supF tests are clearly significant but in levels (`sctest(fs_lev)`) the test statistic is "only" 82.79 while in logs (`sctest(fs_log)`) it is 282.46. Also, the two peaks pertaining to the two breakpoints can be seen much better when analyzing the data in logs.

Similarly, the breakpoint estimates are somewhat better and the confidence intervals much narrower for the log-transformed data. In levels, we get:

```
confint(bp_lev, breaks = 2, vcov = NeweyWest)
## 
##          Confidence intervals for breakpoints
##          of optimal 3-segment partition: 
## 
## Call:
## confint.breakpointsfull(object = bp_lev, breaks = 2, vcov. = NeweyWest)
## 
## Breakpoints at observation number:
##   2.5 % breakpoints 97.5 %
## 1    NA         125     NA
## 2   202         242    263
```

plus an error message and warnings which all reflect that the asymptotic inference is not a useful approximation here. In contrast, the confidence intervals are quite reasonable for the analysis in logs. Due to the increased variance in the middle segment, its start and end are somewhat more uncertain than for the first and last segment:

```
confint(bp_log, breaks = 2, vcov = NeweyWest)
## 
##          Confidence intervals for breakpoints
##          of optimal 3-segment partition: 
## 
## Call:
## confint.breakpointsfull(object = bp_log, breaks = 2, vcov. = NeweyWest)
## 
## Breakpoints at observation number:
##   2.5 % breakpoints 97.5 %
## 1   107         119    121
## 2   238         240    250
## 
## Corresponding to breakdates:
##   2.5 %    breakpoints 97.5 %  
## 1 1993(11) 1994(11)    1995(1) 
## 2 2004(10) 2004(12)    2005(10)
```

Finally, the replication code for the figure above is included here. The confidence intervals for the breakpoints in levels are cannot added in the graphic due to the error mentioned above. Hence, only the log-transformed series also has the confidence intervals.

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
plot(Thames, main = "Thames")
lines(fitted(bp_lev, breaks = 2), col = 4, lwd = 2)
plot(log(Thames), main = "log(Thames)")
lines(fitted(bp_log, breaks = 2), col = 4, lwd = 2)
lines(confint(bp_log, breaks = 2, vcov = NeweyWest))
plot(fs_lev, main = "supF test")
plot(fs_log, main = "supF test")
plot(bp_lev)
plot(bp_log)
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent and helpful responses to my questions.